# Calculating the the Probability of a sample

Tags: r

The Automobile Association gave the average price of unleaded petrol in
Sweden as 14,63 Swedish Krona (SK) per litre in June 2012. Assume this
price is the population mean, and that the population standard deviation is
sd = 1 SK.

What is the probability that the mean price for a sample of 30 petrol
stations is within 0,25 SK of the population mean?

This is a Question from our University without any way of solution. The result is:0,8296

My way to solve

```
sd=1
mean =14.63

rnorm2 <- function(n,mean,sd) { mean+sd*scale(rnorm(n)) }
value <- rnorm2(30,mean,sd)
mean(r)  ## 4
sd(r)    ## 1

1-pnorm(mean,value,sd)



   solution = 1-1/sqrt(30)
```

the solution is in my calculation:0.8174258

How should i solve this kind of excercises?

Comment: Are you sure "the mean price for a sample of 30 petrol stations is within 0,25 SK of the population mean" can give a result around 0.8?  0,25 SK is far less than the mean 14,63, so the probability would be close to 0....

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding. I believe he means the sample mean of the 30 will be 14.63 plus or minus .25

Comment: @SmokeyShakers In that case the probability should be `0.1974127`... still not the solution from OP's post

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding this is our execise, maybe there is a failure inside, i also get the 0.197

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding, no .1974127 would be the probability of selecting 1 station within .25 of the mean

Comment: @SmokeyShakers yes this is for 1 Station, but i dont know how to do it for 30 stations or the next one would be with 50 Station. maybe it's About Standard Deviation error?

Comment: You have the distribution of population. What you need to do is calculate the [distribution of the sample mean](https://bolt.mph.ufl.edu/6050-6052/module-9/sampling-distribution-of-x-bar/)

Comment: @SmokeyShakers this would be with sd=1 => 1-sd/sqrt(30) the result is 0.8174258 (solution from my calculation) instead of 0,8296 (Solutions from the book)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the Central limit theorem, you can simplify your mathematical problem to the problem `Pr(abs(X)<= 0.25*sqrt(n))`, where `X~N(0,1)`

```
p <- diff(pnorm(c(-0.25,0.25)*sqrt(n)))
```

which gives

```
> p
[1] 0.8290965
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are your population parameters:

```
.sd <- 1
.mean <- 14.63
```

Here is your sample size:

```
n <- 30
```

So your Sampling Distribution parameters are:

```
.sd.s <- .sd/sqrt(n)
.means.s <- .mean
```

So the probability of a sample mean being in between 14.38 and 14.88 is:

```
diff(pnorm(c(14.38,14.88, mean = .mean.s, sd = .sd.s, lower.tail = T)
```